# error: request for member 'show' is ambiguous in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, centos7, qwidget

i've Qt 5.7 in Centos 7 in VM, i am trying to build small program spreadsheet reader.

```
#include "mymainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w;
    w.show(); // <-- ambiguity

    return a.exec();
}
```

this file shows error :-
in qwidget.h :-

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    // Widget management functions

    virtual void setVisible(bool visible);
    void setHidden(bool hidden);
    void show(); // <-- here is showing error
    void hide();

    void showMinimized();
    void showMaximized();
    void showFullScreen();
    void showNormal();

    bool close();
    void raise();
    void lower();
```

Comment: Please show the class definition for `MyMainWindow`.  Does it have a `show` member function of its own declared?

Comment: ok, then update the code with the code you wrote so i cant make assumptions about the app

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is renaming the 'show' function of the 'MyMainWindow' class to another name such as show2 or anything.
Alternatively, another way is calling QMainWindow::show in the main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w;
    w.QMainWindow::show(); 

    return a.exec();
}
```